# serving mp4 files with WebSphere

Tags: ios, video, websphere, mp4

I'm using an old WebSphere Application Server 5.1 to serve mp4 files. I have two problems:

- iOS devices are not able to play these videos
- all other devices can play them but it's impossible to seek beyond the downloaded portion of the file

I think that both issues are caused by the server that is not configured to accept byte-range requests. In fact, there isn't any Accept-Ranges or Content-Range response header.

Am I right? How is it possible to configure WebSphere to accept byte-range requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue/limitation of that version of WAS. The best solution is to serve mp4 files from IHS.